Connect host to a virtual serial device inside a docker container
I have a virtual serial device which is created by Renode inside a docker container. I would like to access the device from my host.
The device is created inside the container at /platform/term. I can use minicom inside the container and read the serial data.
I have tried using a bind mount to share the platform directory with the host, but the device does not show any data in minicom.
I have seen examples of using socat to share the connection over the network, but these examples have failed for me.
Googling this is a total nightmare as every result shows me how to connect a host device to the container, I want the other way around.

Update:
I managed to get it working with socat running:
Terminal 1 (Container): socat TCP-LISTEN:7777,reuseaddr,fork FILE:./platform/term,raw,echo=0,b115200
Terminal 2 (Host): socat PTY,link=/tmp/ttyV0,raw,echo=0,waitslave TCP:localhost:7777
Terminal 3 (Container) docker compose exec devenv renode -e s platform/platform.resc
Terminal 4 (Host): minicom -D /dev/ttyV0
Making sure to share the port 7777 between my container and host
However, my question still stands about why I cant just bind mount the file

Docker containers share the host's kernel (which may be inside a Linux VM) and don't have "virtual devices".  What code is creating and using this device?  What sort of Docker installation do you have?

Perhaps my terminology is wrong. I am using  Renode and creating the device with the command emulation CreateUartPtyTerminal "term" "./platform/term" https://renode.readthedocs.io/en/latest/host-integration/uart.html
I have a docker container based off the ubuntu image. I just installed docker with apt
